# How to create ArticleType via Apex?

Tags: apex, knowledge

I am developing a test Class for a Controller .To have a sufficient test coverage I want to create ArticleTypes (_KAV) via Apex.

Is this possible ,if so then how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that a dedicated sObject will be available for each Article Type. It will follow the format `<ArticleType>__kav` for the KnowledgeArticleVersion. If your article type was `FAQ` then you could create a an instance as follows:

```
FAQ__kav testFaq = new FAQ__kav();
testFaq.Title = 'Test FAQ';
testFaq.Summary = 'KB Summary';
testFaq.URLName = 'test';
insert testFaq;

// Get the KnowledgeArticleId
FAQ__kav insertedTestFaq = [Select KnowledgeArticleId from FAQ__kav where ID = :testFaq.Id];

// Publish
KbManagement.PublishingService.publishArticle(insertedTestFaq.KnowledgeArticleId, true);
```

See also:

- [Articles](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_guidelines_knowledge.htm)

Comment: I wonder if you will need to run it as a user who has knowledge licenses.

Comment: @DanielHoechst Maybe, I don't know. A `System.runAs(user)` may be required. The PublishStatus may need to be kept as 'Draft' rather than 'Online'. There aren't many examples of testing article types online that I can find.